# How to access private fields in inheritance

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design

Suppose I have a class name **Employee**

```
class Employee
{
   int empID;
   String name;
   public Employee(int empID,String name)
   {
     this.empID = empID;
     this.name = name;
   }
   // getters and setters
}
```

Now I create subclass based on their position

```
class Manager extends Employee
{
  private String salary;
  private int deptID;
  public Manager(String salary, int deptID,int id, String name)
  {
    super(id,name);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.deptID = deptID;
  }
  // getters and setters 
 }
```

If I want to access the empID and name of Manager from Manager class, how can I do that as those fields are private? I was thinking in the getter function in Manager class ,I would do super.getName() and super.getID()?

If there is anything wrong in class design pattern, please let me know. I want to make it as perfect as it can be. Thanks for help.

Comment: The fields are not private!

Comment: `empID` and `name` is not *private* but *package-private*. Also what exactly is your question? Did you try to use `super.getName()` and `super.getID()` and failed? If so what was the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use protected variables they can be accessed by any class that inherits them.

```
class Employee
{
   protected int empID;
   protected String name;
   public Employee(int empID,String name)
   {
     this.empID = empID;
     this.name = name;
   }
}

class Manager extends Employee
{
  private String salary;
  private int deptID;
  public Manager(String salary, int deptID,int id, String name)
  {
    super(id,name);
    this.salary = salary;
    this.deptID = deptID;

    // Can access protected variables
    empID = 0;
  }
 }
```

Otherwise you can use getters and setters with the protected or public accessor with your variables being marked as private.

Currently your variables are marked as default (no specified accessor) you can see what the different accessor allow you to do here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

Change `private` to `protected` in order to allow the sub classes to have direct access to parent fields but yet preventing other classes to have direct access.

```
 private String salary;
  private int deptID;
```

to

```
protected String salary;
  protected int deptID;
```

Or You can create getter/setter (with proper access modifier) in parent class and invoke them from child class E.g. `super.getFoo()`

Answer (score 1):

As you have it, base class variables are by default *package private*, having private access in derived class. In that sense, getter methods can be used for this cause, and are available on derived classes. Please though have in mind that getters are normal methods and perform late binding, so be careful not to  apply same getter methods on derived classes which do something else, or else you will lose access to base variables, in a sense.

Comment: Unqualified fields are *package private*, not protected.

Comment: Right, my bad. Updated the answer. Is it ok?